# ifelse function instead of for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the original R code as below.

```
 Bernoulli <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5)
 mix.sample <- rep(0, 1000)  #reserve storage
 for (i in 1:1000) { #for each Bernoulli realization
   if (Bernoulli[i] == 1){ #sample corresponding normal component
     mix.sample[i] <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=1)
   }
   else {
     mix.sample[i] <- rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1)
   }
 }
 plot(density(mix.sample))
```

And I tried the following code instead of the for loop, but there appears a problem with the results been produced, could anyone help me out?

```
 Bernorm <- ifelse(Bernoulli == 1, rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `for` loop you could do

```
set.seed(42)
sim.fun <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    rnorm(1, 10, 1)
  } else {
    rnorm(1, 0, 1)
  }
}

P <- sapply(Bernoulli, sim.fun)
plot(density(P))
```

Or, if you rely on `ifelse()` use it with `sapply()`:

```
P <- sapply(Bernoulli, function(x) ifelse(x == 1, rnorm(1, 10, 1), rnorm(1, 0, 1)))
```

The function is faster though.

`microbenchmark()` yields:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
for-loop 8.015976 8.232972 8.712522 8.316147 8.475865 14.65216   100   c
 sim.fun 3.622982 3.672990 4.493131 3.700290 3.752339 54.14139   100 a  
  sapply 5.932761 6.016319 6.479058 6.070026 6.115951 12.38065   100  b
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use the fact that you can convert the `Binomial` to `logical` right away.

```
  Bernoulli <- as.logical(rbinom(1e3, 1, 0.5))
  samp <- numeric(1e3)
  n <- sum(Bernoulli)
  samp[Bernoulli] <- rnorm(n, 10, 1)
  samp[!Bernoulli] <- rnorm(1e3 - n)
  samp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you create the entire test vector at once (`rbinom`), you could create all values of both `rnorm` vectors once. Put everything in a matrix, use the value of the test vector to select either of the two value columns.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 8
m <- cbind(test = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5),
           norm0 = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
           norm10 = rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 1))

m <- cbind(m, res = m[cbind(1:nrow(m), (m[ , "test"] == 1) + 2)])
#     test      norm0    norm10        res
# [1,]   0  0.3295078  9.378759  0.3295078
# [2,]   0 -0.8204684  7.785300 -0.8204684
# [3,]   1  0.4874291 11.124931 11.1249309
# [4,]   1  0.7383247  9.955066  9.9550664
# [5,]   0  0.5757814  9.983810  0.5757814
# [6,]   1 -0.3053884 10.943836 10.9438362
# [7,]   1  1.5117812 10.821221 10.8212212
# [8,]   1  0.3898432 10.593901 10.5939013
# [10,]  0  1.1249309 10.619826  1.1249309
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put the values in a dataframe, then to add a variable using ifelse like you tried at the beginning. Here I also just plot up the data, but you could assign it back to store the values.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(81)
df <- data_frame(Bernoulli = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.5))

df %>% 
  mutate(mix.sample = if_else(Bernoulli == 1, 
                              rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=1), 
                              rnorm(1, mean=0, sd=1))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mix.sample))+
  geom_density()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 15))
```

[image]